# Неофициальное географическое название. Прописная или строчная?

Tags: орфография

Как пишется: ***русский Север, Русский Север, русский север или Русский север?***
В Интернете в разных статьях нашла варианты - ***русский Север, Русский Север***. В словаре Д.Э. Розенталя "Прописная или строчная?" этого сочетания нет.

Нашла и такой материал: "3.7.14.    **Неофициальные названия географических единиц, частей стран**

В этих названиях все слова, кроме родовых (берег, побережье, материк, континент и т. п.), пишутся с прописной буквы. Напр.: Азиатский материк, Атлантическое побережье, Верхнее Поволжье, Восточная Сибирь, Восточное побережье США, Европейский континент, Забайкалье, Закавказье, Западная Сибирь, Заполярье, Нижнее Поволжье, Новый Свет, Оренбуржье, Подмосковье, Полтавщина, Предуралье, Приамурье, Прибалтика, Приднестровье, Приморье, Северный Кавказ, Северный Урал, Смоленщина, Средняя Азия, Ставрополье, Старый Свет, Центральный Тянь-Шань, Черноморское побережье, Юго-Восточная Азия, Южный берег Крыма, Южный Урал". [Прописная или строчная?](http://www.diamondsteel.ru/useful/handbook/3.html)

**Русский Север?**

Comment: Екатерина, зачем ставить, три "?" подряд, разве это правильно?

Comment: Неправильно, но ставят часто для выражения крайней заинтересованности в получении ответа. Спасибо!

Comment: Я не Екатерина, но пунктуационный знак в виде трех вопросительных (как единое целое) вполне допустим. Другое дело, нужен ли он в этом конкретном месте? По мне так - скорее нет, чем да, текст не настолько эмоциональен Но это решать автору.

Comment: Хм, мне казалось, что это в любом случае дурной стиль (или не знаю, как правильнее назвать), но поверю вам обоим. Заметил в своём комментарии непонятную запятую после "ставить", случайно поставил, видимо, жаль, что не исправить уже! ((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Как пишется: ***русский Север, Русский Север, русский север или
>   Русский север?***

В словаре ***Лопатина, Нечаевой и Чельцовой "Прописная или строчная" (М., 2007)*** — оба слова с прописной:

> **Русский Север**

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, что есть мотивация для всех четырех (как минимум - трех) вариантов написания, с несколько разным смыслом.

**русский Север** - здесь "Север" с заглавной поскольку имеется в виду некая географическая область, а в таких значения стороны света пишутся с заглавной. А "русский" здесь не относится к имени собственному, т. е. значение нарицательное.

**Русский Север** - а это как имя собственное, всё вместе. Про заглавную в "Север" - см. предыдущее.

**Русский север** - ну и, наконец, этот вариант, в котором имя собственное состоит из двух слов, но "север" подразумевает не топоним, а сторону света.

Лопатин, думаю, прав, указывая вариант "Русский Север" нормативным - наиболее естественный и употребительный как имя собственное, хотя по изложенным причинам - не единственно возможное. Если нет весомых причин считать, что у автора какое-то особое по семантике употребление, то так и надо писать.

Answer (score 0):

Если имеется в виду парк, то "Русский Север". Если в значении: "русский юг", "русский восток" и совсем забавное - "русский запад", то, конечно - "русский север". Современные "ура-патриоты" стали писать оба слова с прописной буквы...